# "Incorrect string value" in MySQL user function

Tags: mysql, uuid, stored-functions

I need this function to work in MySQL; I've been trying for a few hours but without results.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `generateGUID`(
    `playerid` BIGINT
) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE temp text;
DECLARE i int UNSIGNED;

SET temp = '';
SET i = 0;

WHILE i < 8 DO
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp, CHAR(playerid & 0xFF));
    SET playerid = playerid >> 8;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

SET temp = MD5(CONCAT("BE", temp));

RETURN temp;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

It's a function that gets a number (a Steam ID) and returns a converted string.

The function is from a github repo, but it's old and it seems that the author is not updating it.

I get:

```
Error de SQL (1366): Incorrect string value: '\x97' for column 'temp' at row 1
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? And what errors do you get?

Comment: Why don't you just use the builtin [UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function?

Comment: Also when you ask for help with an error, you should include the error!

Comment: @LSerni Its Mysql 5.7.2 And After some edit i get this error:

Error de SQL (1366): Incorrect string value: '\x97' for column 'temp' at row 1

Comment: @BillKarwin

Updated in main POST

Comment: Its happening only with the full steam id. If i remove 1 numnbre is doing it ok :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this function *do*? It apparently calculates the [BattlEye ID](https://gist.github.com/Fank/11127158):

```
md5("BE" (2 bytes) + 64-bit SteamID (8 bytes))
```

Where...

```
WHILE i < 8 DO
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp, CHAR(playerid & 0xFF));
    SET playerid = playerid >> 8;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

...the first piece taken is the least significant byte, and it ends up at the beginning of the string. So the number is "little endian".

And this becomes the GUID.

*We can rebuild him. We have the technology*.

A function that generates binary data is `UNHEX`, and we must feed to it a 16-character sequence padded with zeroes. `LPAD` is our friend. Then the number is little endian, and we must then employ `REVERSE`. The rest follows.

Note that **you don't need the function at all**, just the core (the object returned).

```
DROP FUNCTION generateGUID;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `generateGUID`(
    `playerid` BIGINT
) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

RETURN  MD5(
  CONCAT(
    'BE',
    REVERSE(
      UNHEX(
        LPAD(
          HEX(playerid),
          16,
          '0'
        )
      )
    )
  )
);

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And the test:

```
select generateGUID(76532298015716211) -- found on an online generator
```

returns `f276e058bbaaff85d23070c9bd43e2aa` as expected.